# Removing the debugging bar from cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am creating a new project in cakephp, I completly customized the view page, but since I am new to cakephp framework unable to understand how to remove the debugging bar given bottom of the page. I checked and tried every possible things, but not getting. Any suggestion will be appreciated. I am using cakephp-3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it not as simple as amending config/app.php and changing the debug paramter to false

```
'debug' => false
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative. On cakephp 3.x, in **config/bootstrap.php** file, try **after**:

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}

//add this
Plugin::unload('DebugKit');
```

sorry for my bad english but i am Brazilian :-)

Answer (score -1):

Go to `core.php` file `in app/config` folder 
set `Configure::write('debug', 0);`